# Attach sbt plugin to compile lifecycle

Tags: scala, sbt

Let's suppose the following auto plugin:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object TestPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {
    val myTask = TaskKey[Unit]("myTask", "It's just a task")
  }
  import autoImport._

  override def trigger = allRequirements

  def doSomething = (streams) map { (s) => 
    s.log.info(s"Something...")    
  }

  override lazy val buildSettings = Seq(
    myTask <<= doSomething
  )

}
```

I would like this plugin to run before compilation. When I type in the sbt console `compile`, this plugin runs (before the actual compilation happens)

I could use the following in the sbt configuration of the project where I will use this plugin:

```
(compile in Compile) <<= (compile in Compile)  dependsOn myTask
```

However, I'd rather have the plugin attach itself to the compilation process without having to explicity declare it in each project where I will use my plugin.

If I try to copy the line before in my plugin `buildSettings` I get the error:

```
[error]   {.}/compile:compile from {.}/compile:compile ((TestPlugin) TestPlugin.scala:32)
[error]      Did you mean compile:compile ?
```

Any idea how I could get it working?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `projectSettings` and not `buildSettings`. This way, the settings are applied in the scope of the individual project, which in turn should have the `compile:compile` setting already defined and adding the line

```
(compile in Compile) <<= (compile in Compile)  dependsOn myTask
```

to the `projectSettings` should work as expected.